# NetBeans 8.2 Clang C++ project tries to debug with gdb instead of lldb

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, netbeans

I created a simple C++ app project in NetBeans using the built-in "Clang" tool collection. The Clang settings seem to be fine (all points to LLVM):

> C compiler: /usr/bin/clang
>   C++ compiler: /usr/bin/clang++
>   ...
>   Debugger command: /usr/bin/lldb

and my project settings have "Tool Collection" set to: "CLang (Default)".

When I try to debug the project, the GDB debugger is being fired (and fails of course due to known gdb issues on the newest Mac systems, 
which is one of the reasons I switched to LLVM) I get:

> Starting Debugger...
>   Starting gdb
>   ...
>   GDB has unexpectedly stopped with return 0

I tried to force the Debug command to use lldb in the Debug projects settings but to no avail. 
It is also strange that when using "Attach debugger..." I can only see all GDB debuggers I installed but no lldb (see screenshots below).

What is the setting I am missing?

**SCREENSHOTS:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as you can read in the [NetBeans documentation](https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/cnd/debugging.html), the lldb compiler is not supported yet.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).